# CellIdentity Classes in android

Tags: android, cell, telephony

Can anybody tell how to use these classes and their functions (make an object etc)

```
  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityGsm.html

  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityCdma.html

  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityLte.html
```

is their any direct method or indirect. I cant find anything about them these are added in API level 17. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

here's the information you need:

1. [LINK](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/telephony/java/android/telephony/CellIdentityGsm.java?repo=platform--frameworks--base)
2. [LINK](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/telephony/java/android/telephony/CellIdentityCdma.java?repo=platform--frameworks--base&name=jb-mr1-release&r=4046e012887fff1f36dfd3eddc6f354d4c2497fc)
3. [LINK](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/telephony/java/android/telephony/CellIdentityLte.java?repo=platform--frameworks--base)

If you can't use those, then see [here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) (maybe [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1966025) too).

cheers

Comment: these are only just the classes let say I included them in my project and then use CellIdentityGsm foo=new CellIdentityGsm() this constructor now foo.getCid() will return zero or nothing

Comment: it is the LAC and CID of Neighboring-cells but i want CID and LAC of my device.